# Readers blocking reader on readable secondaries

Tags: sql-server, performance, availability-groups, sql-server-2017, blocking

We recently migrated to AG setup for one of our VLDB's around 20+TB.

Current setup is Multi subnet AG with primary accepting mix workload while heavy reporting offloaded to readable secondary replicas.

Database in question has RCSI isolation level setup on primary.

Now i do not understand why we are seeing blocking on secondary where readers are blocking readers. I previously had a question where a DDL change in primary made REDO thread on secondary wait due to SCH_M locks but now situation is different.

I am seeing some basic SELECT queries blocking other SELECT queries. Why is this happening on the readable S replica?

Also the tables in this VLDB are majorly partitioned. Does having or setting lock escalation to auto help? Currently set to Table as default for VLTbls

Comment: Readable secondaries ALWAYS use Read Committed Snapshot Isolation (RCSI). Under RCSI, readers do not block readers. Can you provide added details on what you're seeing that is bringing you to this conclusion?

Comment: I had this answered on my previous question  that it would be snapshot. Now m confused

Comment: @AMtwo Are there any cases where **readers** would block **readers** anyway, regardless of any **isolation level**? My understanding is such a case isn't possible unless **Lock Hints** were explicitly used.

Comment: @JD On a readable secondary, I believe the locking hints are all ignored anyway. It **must** run in RCSI, which is enforced by the database engine. If there's *blocking* then I'd expect the redo thread to be part of the blocking chain. There's a long list of waits other than blocking that could be involved... But there's not really enough info to say. I'm curious to review the data that lead OP to conclude blocking, then if it's not blocking, dig through session wait stats

Comment: @AMtwo, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/active-secondaries-readable-secondary-replicas-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver15#bkmk_Benefits) states "All queries that run against the secondary databases are automatically mapped to snapshot isolation transaction level, even when other transaction isolation levels are explicitly set. Also, all locking hints are ignored." So the isolation level is `SNAPSHOT`, not `READ COMMITTED` with RCSI. But that's just a technicality here since both use row versioning.

Comment: Ah oh. Good to know. But yes, still means readers won't block readers. So everything else I said still stands. We need more info on the blocking and waits to provide a useful answer.